# How to loop over elements in a div using .each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, each

I've tried reading over jQuery's api, but it's only about my second time employing jQuery so I've found myself a bit lost.

I've a div setup with a list of images underneath it.

```
<div id="slides">
    <img src="images/casting1.jpg" alt="Casting on the Upper Kings">
    <img src="images/casting2.jpg" alt="Casting on the Lower Kings">
    <img src="images/casting3.jpg" alt="Casting at another location!">
    <img src="images/catchrelease.jpg" alt="Catch and Release on the Big Horn">
    <img src="images/fish.jpg" alt="Catching on the South Fork">
    <img src="images/fish1.jpg" alt="Catching on the North Fork">
    <img src="images/lures.jpg" alt="The Lures for Catching">
</div>
```

So I first selected the div by using:

```
var slides = $("#slides");
```

But from there I have no idea which direction to head in. How do I select the individual items inside of the div? Any help or guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: `$("#slides").find('img').each( function() { ... do smth with $(this)... });`

Comment: `slides.find("img").each(function(index, element){ /* whatever */ })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` or `contextSelector` to get the children.

```
var $slides = $("#slides");

var allImages = $slides.find('img'); or // $('img', $slides)
```

If you want to iterate over the images, then just use an `each` loop to target each image specifically.

If you want to select a specific image.

```
    $('img', $slides).eq(1)  // Will get you the second image in the div.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#slides img').each(function(){
//code required using $(this).... to target each particular image of that iteration
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices, `.find()` or `.children()`, and `.children('img')` is the same as `.find('> img')`

```
var slides = $("#slides");

slides.children('img').each(function (idx, elem) {
    console.info(idx, elem);
});
```

Comment: according to jquery documentation, each's callback signature is like this:  Function(Integer index, Element element)

Comment: A few more than two actually.... `$('#slides img')`, `$('#slides >')` , and at least a few more would also work (though arguably less efficient )....;)

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
slides.find("img").each(function(index, element){
    //keep in mind, element is a HTMLElement
    //not a JqueryObject, in order to manipulate
    //it with jquery use: $(element)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot...

```
var slides = $("#slides > img").each(function () {});

console.log(slides);
```

That logs an array of all the `img` elements

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each `<img>` using `$("#slides img").each`

```
$("#slides img").each(function(){
  // do something 
});
```

Comment: sorry Manish - already posted that one.. :) nice addition of class name tho

Comment: Also you can use the `index` which is part of `each` instead of creating a variable and incrementing it.

Comment: There would never be a reason to have incremental classes like this. Just do `$('.class-name').eq(0);`,  `$('.class-name').eq(1);`, etc

Comment: thanks for the feedback guys. that was just an example. I will get rid of the example.

Answer (score 0):

Using the variable you already created:

```
slides.children('img').each(function(){
  // here use this for the HTML element or $(this) for the jQuery wrapped one
});
```